# Laravel ajax pagination set page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, laravel-5.1

In my laravel project i use hashes in the url to keep track on selections of the user, so they are able to go back to a filter result. I dont want the page to refresh so I DONT UPDATE THE URL with Page=someid (except the hash) the response of the server looks like.

```
if ($request->ajax()) {      
    //The page I want to select posted with ajax
    $paginaId = $request->input('page');
    //some query like
    $query = Table::Query();
    //get 9 items
    $rooms= $query->paginate(9);
    //Return the response
    return Response::json(View::make('front.rooms.render', array('rooms' => $rooms))->render());
}
```

The $paginaId  represents the selected pagination page. Everything works fine except one part. I cant set the current page of the pagination. I viewed the [documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html#method_currentPage) but couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: I'm tried with your controller and with a jquery post, and it works fine. The pagination is inside template, and the current page will be setted automatically, if your render the pagination inside the template.

Comment: @lamzozo the question is how i can set the current page. (normaly its based ont he url page=pageid value. but i dont set it and want to set the selected page in my controller manualy. The code i have works but i need to set the page manualy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 $rooms = $query->paginate(9, ['*'], 'page', $paginaId);
```

In this case you can set $paginaId manualy

Comment: Checked the source, but it's in the API:
http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate